# Can't record audio in Davinci Resolve

Tags: nvidia, sound, microphone, pipewire, davinci-resolve

I have downloaded the free version of Resolve 18.5 beta 4 and installed it on Ubuntu 23.10.Everything is working fine except the audio recording, there is no option in the sound settings to choose my inputs. I have a presonus usb 96 and a Corsair hs 80 usb headset with mic and they work fine in every other application.

Nvidia gpu drivers-rtx 3060 12G installed and i am on pipewire audio server using x11 not Wayland.Same problem exists in my other machine with Manjaro Gnome 22,1.

The Ubuntu machine is dual boot with windows 11 and i have disabled the Cpu graphics in bios and use only the Nvidia rtx 3060 12G.Older versions of Ubuntu and older versions of Resolve that I tested had the same problem so I figured if I upgrade to the very newest version the problem would be solved

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 (*mantic*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *mantic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 5 October 2023, and isn't on-topic here until release on 12 October 2023.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-release-schedule/34989  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *mantic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I have reinstalled Ubuntu now version 23.04 and the problem with Davinci Resolve exists.Same problem in Manjaro and Mx Linux.

Comment: I have the problem, too